# is it possible to edit a class file in tomcat and recompile that single file?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a exam system at hand which is written by tomcat , now , i found there is a bug in programme, i don`t have the source code, but i do decompile it using jd-gui, what i want to do 
is simple, just replace this line of code

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select id FROM EXAMINEE ");
```

with

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id FROM EXAMINEE ");
```

How can i do it,i want to compile that single
java file into class,i tried javac,but too many errors,
below are the decompiled file i want to modify

```
package maozf.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import maozf.Databases;
import maozf.ExamPaper;
import maozf.Examinee;
import maozf.Officer;

@WebServlet({"/admin/adminExaminee.jsp"})
public class AdminExaminee
  extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try
    {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      ServletContext application = request.getSession().getServletContext();
      Officer officer = (Officer)session.getAttribute("admin");
      if (officer == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
      }
      String oper = request.getParameter("oper");
      String name = request.getParameter("name");
      String idcard = request.getParameter("idcard");
      String duty = request.getParameter("duty");
      String dept = request.getParameter("dept");
      String area = request.getParameter("area");
      String papertypeid = request.getParameter("papertypeid");
      String id = request.getParameter("id");
      int paperid = 0;
      if (oper == null) {
        oper = "";
      }
      if (name != null) {
        name = new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim();
      }
      if (idcard != null) {
        idcard = new String(idcard.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim();
      }
      if (duty != null) {
        duty = new String(duty.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim();
      }
      if (dept != null) {
        dept = new String(dept.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim();
      }
      if (dept != null) {
        area = new String(area.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim();
      }
      if (papertypeid != null) {
        paperid = Integer.valueOf(papertypeid).intValue();
      }
      id = request.getParameter("id");

      Connection conn = (Connection)application.getAttribute("connect");
      if (conn == null)
      {
        conn = new Databases().getConn();
        application.setAttribute("connect", conn);
      }
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();

      String sqlsString = "";
      if (oper.equals("change"))
      {
        Examinee examinee = new Examinee(id, name, idcard, area, dept, paperid, duty);
        examinee.save(conn);
      }
      else if (oper.equals("bacthChange"))
      {
        String where = " where true ";
        where = where + (area.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and area='").append(area).append("' ").toString());
        where = where + (dept.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and dept='").append(dept).append("' ").toString());
        where = where + (duty.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and duty='").append(duty).append("' ").toString());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id FROM EXAMINEE " + where);
        while (rs.next())
        {
          Examinee examinee = Examinee.LoadExaminee(rs.getString(1), conn);
          examinee.setPaperTypeId(paperid);
          examinee.save(conn);
        }
      }
      else if (oper.equals("batchReset"))
      {
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select id FROM EXAMINEE ");
        while (rs.next())
        {
          Examinee examinee = Examinee.LoadExaminee(rs.getString(1), conn);
          examinee.setExamPaper(ExamPaper.loadMe(examinee, conn));
          examinee.save(conn);
        }
      }
      else if (oper.equals("del"))
      {
        st.execute("delete EXAMINEE where id='" + id + "'");
      }
      else if (oper.equals("bacthDel"))
      {
        String where = " where true ";
        where = where + (area.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and area='").append(area).append("' ").toString());
        where = where + (dept.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and dept='").append(dept).append("' ").toString());
        where = where + (duty.equals("%") ? "" : new StringBuilder(" and duty='").append(duty).append("' ").toString());
        sqlsString = "delete from EXAMINEE" + where;
        st.executeUpdate(sqlsString);
      }
      else if (oper.equals("add"))
      {
        Examinee examinee = new Examinee(id, name, idcard, area, dept, paperid, duty);
        examinee.save(conn);
      }
      else if (oper.equals("resetPaper"))
      {
        Examinee examinee = Examinee.LoadExaminee(id, conn);
        examinee.setExamPaper(ExamPaper.loadMe(examinee, conn));
        examinee.save(conn);
        HashMap<String, ExamPaper> paperMap = (HashMap)application
          .getAttribute("paperMap");
        if (paperMap != null) {
          paperMap.put(examinee.getId(), examinee.getExamPaper());
        }
      }
      String pageString = request.getParameter("page");
      String search = request.getParameter("search");
      String field = request.getParameter("field");
      String sql = "";String countsql = "";
      int pages = 0;int pageCount = 0;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      if (pageString != null)
      {
        pages = Integer.valueOf(pageString).intValue();
        sql = (String)session.getAttribute("sql");
        pageCount = ((Integer)session.getAttribute("pagecount")).intValue();
      }
      else
      {
        if ((field != null) && (search != null) && (search.length() > 0))
        {
          search = new String(search.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8").trim().replaceAll("'", "");
          sql = "select a.* ,b.papertypename from EXAMINEE a left join exampapertype b on a.papertypeid=b.id  where " + 
            field + " like '%" + search + "%' order by a.papertypeid";
          countsql = "select count(1) from EXAMINEE where name like '%" + search + "%'";
        }
        else
        {
          sql = "select a.* ,b.papertypename from EXAMINEE a left join exampapertype b on a.papertypeid=b.id order by a.papertypeid";
          countsql = "select count(1) from EXAMINEE";
        }
        rs = st.executeQuery(countsql);
        rs.next();
        pageCount = rs.getInt(1) / 10;
        session.setAttribute("sql", sql);
        session.setAttribute("pagecount", Integer.valueOf(pageCount));
      }
      st.execute(sql + " limit 10 offset 10*" + pageString);
      rs = st.getResultSet();

      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("head.jsp");
      dispatcher.include(request, response);
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
      out.write("<!--\n");
      out.write("\tfunction isSubmit(){\r\n");
      out.write("\t\tif(confirm(\"确定要重置所有考生的试卷吗?\"))\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\tlocation.href=\"adminExaminee.jsp?oper=batchReset\";\r\n");
      out.write("}\n");
      out.write("//-->\n");
      out.write("</script>\r\n");
      out.write("<div style=\"margin: 0 20px 20px 20px\">\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=block block-user id=block-user-0>\r\n");
      out.write("<h2><span class=w1><span class=w2>考生信息</span></span></h2>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=content>\r\n");
      out.write("<div style=\"margin-top: 5px\" align=right>\r\n");
      out.write("<form action=adminExaminee.jsp method=post\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; display: inline\" align=left><select\r\n");
      out.write("\tname=field>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"name\" selected>按姓名</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"dept\">按部门</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"area\">按单位</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"duty\">按职能</option>\r\n");
      out.write("</select>:<input type=text name=search><input type=image\r\n");
      out.write("\tsrc=\"../images/search.png\" alt=查找></form>\r\n");
      out.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"首页\" src=\"../images/first.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(0);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == 0 ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"上一页\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tsrc=\"../images/previoupage.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pages - 1);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == 0 ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"下一页\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tsrc=\"../images/nextpage.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pages + 1);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == pageCount ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input\r\n");
      out.write("\ttype=\"image\" onfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"末页\" src=\"../images/end.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pageCount);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == pageCount ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write("></div>\r\n");
      out.write("<table CELLSPACING=0 class=admin width=100%>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<TR>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>考生编号</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>考生姓名</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>身份证</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>地区</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>部门</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>职务</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>试卷名称</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th>试卷状态</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<th colspan=3>操作</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</TR>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      while (rs.next())
      {
        InputStream a = rs.getBinaryStream("exampaper");
        ExamPaper examPaper = null;
        if (a != null) {
          try
          {
            examPaper = (ExamPaper)new ObjectInputStream(a).readObject();
          }
          catch (Exception localException1) {}
        }
        out.write("<tr><td>" + 
          rs.getString("ID") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("NAME") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("IDCARD") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("AREA") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("DEPT") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("duty") + 
          "</td><td>" + 
          rs.getString("papertypename") + 
          "</td><td>" + (

          examPaper.getStartTime() == 0L ? "未测试" : examPaper.isEnd() ? "成绩:" + examPaper.getScoring() : examPaper == null ? "未生成试卷" : "正在测试中") + 
          "</td><td><a href=adminExaminee.jsp?oper=resetPaper&id=" + rs.getString("ID") + 
          ">重置试卷</a></td><td><a href=adminExaminee.jsp?oper=changeShow&id=" + rs.getString("ID") + 
          "#add>修改</a></td><td><a href=adminExaminee.jsp?oper=del&id=" + rs.getString("ID") + 
          ">删除</a></td></tr>");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</table>\r\n");
      out.write("<div style=\"margin-top: 5px\" align=right><input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"首页\" src=\"../images/first.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(0);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == 0 ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"上一页\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tsrc=\"../images/previoupage.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pages - 1);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == 0 ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"image\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"下一页\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tsrc=\"../images/nextpage.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pages + 1);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == pageCount ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write(">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input\r\n");
      out.write("\ttype=\"image\" onfocus=\"this.blur()\" unselectable=\"on\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tstyle=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\" alt=\"末页\" src=\"../images/end.png\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonclick=\"location.href='adminExaminee.jsp?page=");
      out.print(pageCount);
      out.write("'\"\r\n");
      out.write("\t");
      out.print(pages == pageCount ? "DISABLED" : "");
      out.write("></div>\r\n");
      out.write("<div><input type=button onclick=\"isSubmit()\" value=\"所有人员试卷重置\">\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("<hr>\r\n");
      out.write("<a name=\"add\">\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=block block-user id=block-user-0>\r\n");
      out.write("<h2><span class=w1><span class=w2> ");
      if (oper.equals("changeShow"))
      {
        out.write("修改考生信息<button onclick='location.href=\"adminExaminee.jsp#add\"'>切换为新增</button>");
        st.execute("select * from EXAMINEE where ID='" + id + "' order by papertypeid");
        rs = st.getResultSet();
        if (rs.next())
        {
          name = rs.getString("NAME");
          idcard = rs.getString("IDCARD");
          area = rs.getString("AREA");
          dept = rs.getString("DEPT");
          duty = rs.getString("duty");
          paperid = rs.getInt("papertypeid");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        out.write("添加考生信息");
      }
      out.write(" </span></span></h2>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=content>\r\n");
      out.write("<form class=admin action=adminExaminee.jsp method=\"post\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonsubmit=\"return checkForm();\">\r\n");
      out.write("<table>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>考生编号:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=\"id\" name=id\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + id + " readonly" : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>考生姓名:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=\"name\" name=name\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + name : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>身&nbsp;份&nbsp;证:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=idcard name=idcard\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + idcard : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>所在地区:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=dept name=area\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + area : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>所在部门:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=dept name=dept\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + dept : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>职&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;务:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><input type=text id=duty name=duty\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "value=" + duty : "");
      out.write(" /></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td>试卷类型:</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td><select name=papertypeid>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");

      st.execute("select id,papertypename from exampapertype");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next())
      {
        String seleted = "";
        if (rs.getInt(1) == Integer.valueOf(paperid).intValue()) {
          seleted = "seleted";
        }
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getInt(1) + "\" " + seleted + ">" + rs.getString(2) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t</select></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<td colspan=2 align=center><input type=hidden name=oper\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\tvalue='");
      out.print(oper.equals("changeShow") ? "change" : "add");
      out.write("' /> <input\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\ttype=submit value=\"确定 [O]\" /  accesskey=\"o\"></td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("</table>\r\n");
      out.write("</form>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("<hr>\r\n");
      out.write("<a name=\"bacthAdd\"></a>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=block block-user id=block-user-0>\r\n");
      out.write("<h2><span class=w1><span class=w2>批量导入</span></span></h2>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=content>\r\n");
      out.write("<form action=\"bacthAddExaminee\" id=BacthAddExaminee\r\n");
      out.write("\tenctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonsubmit=\"return checkUpload();\"><input type=hidden name=oper\r\n");
      out.write("\tvalue='bacthAdd'> EXCEL文件:<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tsize=\"45\"> <input type=\"submit\" value=\"提 交[U]\" accesskey=\"u\"></form>\r\n");
      out.write("<p>具体格式请下载样本文档。&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=\"../BacthAddExaminee.xls\">下载格式文档</a>\r\n");
      out.write("</p>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("<hr>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=block block-user id=block-user-0>\r\n");
      out.write("<h2><span class=w1><span class=w2>批量修改</span></span></h2>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=content>\r\n");
      out.write("<form action=\"adminExaminee.jsp\"><input type=hidden name=oper\r\n");
      out.write("\tvalue='bacthChange'> 地区:<select name=area>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct area from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 部门:<select name=dept>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct dept from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 职务:<select name=duty>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct duty from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 试卷类型:<select name=papertypeid>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select id,papertypename from exampapertype");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(2) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"submit\" value=\"提 交[C]\"\r\n");
      out.write("\taccesskey=\"c\"></form>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("<hr>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=block block-user id=block-user-0>\r\n");
      out.write("<h2><span class=w1><span class=w2>批量删除</span></span></h2>\r\n");
      out.write("<div class=content>\r\n");
      out.write("<form action=\"adminExaminee.jsp\" id=BacthDel method=\"post\"\r\n");
      out.write("\tonsubmit=\"return confirm('确定要全部删除指定的考生!')\"><input type=hidden\r\n");
      out.write("\tname=oper value='bacthDel'> 地区:<select name=area>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<br>\r\n");
      out.write("\t>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct area from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 部门:<select name=dept>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<br>\r\n");
      out.write("\t>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct dept from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 职务:<select name=duty>\r\n");
      out.write("\t<option value=\"%\" selected>全部</option>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

      st.execute("select distinct duty from examinee");
      rs = st.getResultSet();
      while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>)");
      }
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"submit\" value=\"提 交[D]\"\r\n");
      out.write("\taccesskey=\"d\"></form>\r\n");
      out.write("</div>\r\n");
      out.write("</div></div>\r\n");
      out.write("</body>\r\n");
      out.write("<script>\r\n");
      out.write("function checkUpload() {\r\n");
      out.write("\t  var ext =BacthAddExaminee.file.value;\r\n");
      out.write("\t  ext = ext.substring(ext.length-4,ext.length);\r\n");
      out.write("\t  ext = ext.toLowerCase();\r\n");
      out.write("\t  if(ext != '.xls' || ext.length==null) {\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t \talert(\"你选择的文件不是.xls文件\"); \r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\treturn false;\r\n");
      out.write("\t  }else{\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t  \tshowWaiting();\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t \treturn true;\r\n");
      out.write("\t  }\r\n");
      out.write("}\r\n");
      out.write("function checkForm() {\r\n");
      out.write("\t  if(document.getElementById(\"id\").value.length==0||document.getElementById(\"name\").value.length==0||document.getElementById(\"idcard\").value.length==0||document.getElementById(\"dept\").value.length==0||document.getElementById(\"duty\").value.length==0){\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t  alert(\"有项目未输入必要的内容!\");\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t  return false;\r\n");
      out.write("\t  } else{\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t  return true;\r\n");
      out.write("\t  }\r\n");
      out.write("}\r\n");
      out.write("</script>\r\n");

      out.write("</html>\r\n");

      st.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      out.write("<script>alert('添加失败,可能你要添加的ID已经存在!')</script>");
      out.write("</html>\r\n");
    }
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    doPost(request, response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to compile one single file on its own. The file has many dependencies (its importing and using many other classes). What you can do is take all the class files which are the part of the same project as your `AdminExaminee` class is, then:
1. Make a project in eclipse using all the class files (after de compiling them)
2. Modify the required class files (`AdminExaminee` in your case)
3. Compile the project
4. Replace the old class file with new class file

This may not be the best possible solution available but it will definitely work. I had faced similar issue in the past and I used the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy exploded application

means  your code is in individual .class files instead of .jar files,

then you can do replace individual files.

The problem is that Java class loaders in general, and Tomcat class loader specifically, may not replace a class that is already in the memory.

it will not get replaced.

So, you'll have to restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Karibasappa's answer.
If you check the exploded war file, there might not be no separate classes in the WEB-INF folder. You will have to create a folder called 'classes' inside WEB-INF. Put the class file you required into the correct package structure (create the folders as you require) and then restart tomcat.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i do have 'classes' folder inside WEB-INF,the problem is i don`t know how to compile that individual java file back into class,pls show me how

Comment: To compile a java file, use the command "javac <your_filename>.java". This will generate associated class file

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the dependancies[the files that were imported], it may not be possible to compile just that class outside using javac. You have to create a new project, decompile all the classes and add as java files, make your changes and give a build. Best is deploy entire war instead of making changes to the exploded war.